# how to handle retry-after with WebResponse in a using block

Tags: c#, try-catch, using, webresponse

I have my `WebResponse` wrapped in `using` blocks:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
// do things...
}
```

The webservice I'm calling will raise [429's](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#page-3) with a [Retry-After](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.37) in the header.

If I wrap this in a `try-catch` to listen for the `WebException` then I will lose the context of the response and won't be able to read the `Retry-After` element in the header.

How should I properly handle the response while also implementing retry logic for this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was much easier than I thought.

The [WebException class exposes a .Response property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which I can use to read the items in the response (if any was sent).